# Can I pass in block as a variable with "gsub!"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I can do:

```
'string'.gsub!(/something/) do
  ... complex replacement here ...
  'final result'
end
```

I was wondering if it is possible to assign the `do ... end` block to a variable and pass in to `gsub!` as a parameter so that I could do something like:

```
my_block_replacement_logic = {
  ... complex replacement here ...
  'final result'
}
```

and then call `gsub` with:

```
this_string.gsub!(/something/, my_block_replacement_logic)
that_string.gsub!(/something/, my_block_replacement_logic)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can define your behaviour in a proc and assign that to a variable. Then you can later pass that to your `gsub!` using a special syntax by prepending  a `&` to the variable name.

```
my_proc = proc do
  # ... complex replacement here ...
  'final result'
end

'string'.gsub!(/something/, &my_proc)
```

Comment: Amazing, I thought it was similar, I was missing the &. Will accept as soon as SO allows me.